VBA - Search Website, Return Class Element Value
I've created a VBA Script to return a value from a class element value on a website, However this is not working in this particular element. I believe this may be due to the website requiring the page to "load" prior to returning the results.
Is there any current way to return value's from a website's search value without opening a browser?
Thanks in advance.
Sub WebRequestExample()
    Dim url As String
    Dim xmlHttp As Object
    Dim html As Object
    Dim responseText As String
    Dim elements As Object
    Dim elementSpan As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim startTime As Double
    Dim timeoutSeconds As Integer
    ' Define the URL
    url = "https://www.dhl.com/au-en/home/tracking/tracking-express.html?submit=1&tracking-id=2818454203"
    ' Create a new XMLHTTP request
    Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    ' Open the URL
    xmlHttp.Open "GET", url, False
    xmlHttp.Send
    ' Get the response text
    responseText = xmlHttp.responseText
    ' Create a new HTML document
    Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    html.Body.innerHTML = responseText
    ' Set timeout duration in seconds
    timeoutSeconds = 30
    startTime = Timer
    ' Wait for the specific div element by class name to appear
    Do
        Set elements = html.getElementsByClassName("c-tracking-result--delivery-headline level3")
        If elements.Length > 0 Then
            Set elementSpan = elements(0)
            Exit Do
        End If
        DoEvents
    Loop While Timer < startTime + timeoutSeconds
    If Not elementSpan Is Nothing Then
        ' Write the content of the specific div to a specific cell
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Invoice_Template")
        ws.Range("k12").value = elementSpan.innerText
    Else
        ' Handle the case where the element is not found within the timeout period
    End If
    ' Clean up
    Set xmlHttp = Nothing
    Set html = Nothing
    Set elementSpan = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing
End Sub


you probably need some type of onload "function" to delay running the rest of your program until the page loaded.
